# How to expose in a network?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

The below example is from the `docker-compose` [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#version-2).

From my understanding they want to have `redis` port 6379 available in the `web` container.

Why don't they have

```
expose:
  - "6379"
```

in the `redis` container?

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code
    networks:
      - front-tier
      - back-tier
  redis:
    image: redis
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/var/lib/redis
    networks:
      - back-tier
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official Redis image](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/):

> This image includes EXPOSE 6379 (the redis port), so standard
>   container linking will make it automatically available to the linked
>   containers (as the following examples illustrate).

which is pretty much the typical way of doing things.

[Redis Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/master/3.0/Dockerfile#L50).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need links anymore now that we assign containers to docker networks. And without linking, unless you publish all ports with a `docker run -P`, there's no value to exposing a port on the container. Containers can talk to any port opened on any other container if they are on the same network (assuming default settings for ICC), so exposing a port becomes a noop.

Typically, you only expose a port via the Dockerfile as an indicator to those running your image, or to use the `-P` flag. There are also some projects that look at exposed ports of other containers to know how to talk to them, specifically I'm thinking of nginx-proxy, but that's a unique case.

However, *publishing* a port makes that port available from the docker host, which always needs to be done from the docker-compose.yml or run command (you don't want image authors able to affect the docker host without some form of local admin acknowledgement). When you publish a specific port, it doesn't need to be exposed first.